# Why does NUnit not show console output from background threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading, console, nunit

My library has some background threads which print debug output to Console.WriteLine(). On the first test I can see the debug lines from a background thread in the output of the test. But the next tests does not show this output any more.

If I call Console.WriteLine() in the test method itself then this is to see in the test output. I have debugged it and the test call

- first Console.WriteLine() in the test
- then it calls Console.WriteLine() in the background test
- last it calls Console.WriteLine() in the test again.

But I see only the output from the test directly and not the output from the background thread.

It looks like that NUnit has saved the captured scope in the thread context.

How can I get the the console output from all background threads?

Comment: Perhaps you should open an issue with NUnit? No offense, but I doubt anyone else will have an answer.

Comment: Does TestContext.WriteLine() work?

Comment: @RobProuse The library has no access to the NUnit API.

Comment: @RobProuse Thanks for the hint with TestContext.

Comment: @Horcrux7 if you can come up with a minimal repro, please file an issue. We should be capturing Console output for the entire call context.

Answer (score 3):

Because our library has the option to redirect the log output, we can do the following in the tests:

```
    [SetUp]
    public void FixtureSetUp()
    {
        MyLibrary.Console = TestContext.Out;
    }
```

This is not a good solution.

Comment: Only thing that worked for me after 100 trials of other stuff.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the particular runtime build of the NUnit framework you are using. Information pertaining to text capture is maintained in NUnit's `TestExecutionContext`, which is stored differently on different builds.

For all desktop builds (.NET 2.0, 3.5, 4.0 and 4.5) the current `TestExecutionContext` is maintained in the `CallContext`. Since the `TestExecutionClass` implements `ILogicalThreadAffinative`, the context follows the test as new threads are created.

For our two .NET Standard builds (1.3 and 1.6) the context is kept in Thread Local Storage and therefore does not follow the creation of new threads. This is a limitation we hope to overcome when there is a .NET Standard 2.0 build.

Comment: You mean of the answer? Is that a done thing here? My approach elsewhere is to let old answers stand, whether correct or incorrect, because they are... historical. :-)

Answer (score 0):

One workaround that I've found is to use [NUnitLiteRunner](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/running-tests/NUnitLite-Runner.html) and have your own `Main` methid like this:

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static TextWriter ConsoleOut { get; private set; }
    public static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        ConsoleOut = Console.Out;
        return new AutoRun().Execute(args);
    }
}
```

Then in some global TestSetupFixture you can restore `Console.Out`:

```cs
[OneTimeSetUp]
public async Task BeforeAll()
{
    // ignore nunit's console capture
    Console.SetOut(Program.ConsoleOut);
}
```

This way you'll loose test output in the final report, but you get your console back.
You could also have a custom `TextWriter` implementation that would write to both original `Console.Out` and to the one substituted by NUnit.